# Eclipse / Maven / SonarQube : Invalid value of sonar.libraries

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, sonarqube

I'm trying to upload my project to a remote sonarqube server.

The project is a multi-module project.

I'm getting an error on the parent project. Sonar's log:

```
[INFO] cv-parent ......................................... FAILURE [  2.962 s]
[INFO] cv-common ......................................... SUCCESS [  1.236 s]
[INFO] cv-backend ........................................ SUCCESS [  2.464 s]
```

Now its reporting an error about Hibernate:

```
[ERROR] [15:04:27.096] Invalid value of sonar.libraries for be.vdab:cv-backend
[ERROR] No files nor directories matching '/Users/knaller/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.1.8.FINAL/hibernate-core-4.1.8.FINAL.jar' in directory /Users/knaller/Documents/Java/cv-parent/cv-backend
```

Does anyone have an idea about what this error means or how to fix it?

Comment: Can you edit your post to give more information? What are you exactly doing? What command are you running? What are the properties in your POM?

Answer (score 7):

I have same issue. By checking the Maven .m2 repo the required file name ends as `Final` instead of `FINAL` - Case Sensitive. I have removed the folder (eg : `/Users/knaller/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.1.8.Final`) and rebuild again. The new folder `4.1.8.FINAL` got downloaded by maven and issue got resolved.

Comment: Great hint - I was struggling with the same issue - finally got resolved. The problem was - that for Sonar - dependencies in pom seem to be case-sensitive ! Once you change your dependent artifactIds to match EXACTLY the project artifactIds - problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fixed it.

This problem was occurring whenever i would do an Maven -> sonar:sonar.

But then i tried the sonar-runner command in the project's home directory and it successfully uploaded it to sonar.

Not sure if this is the 'dirty-way' though but it worked for me.

Thanks